# How can I generate an inter-organizational network from individual data based on carreer trajectories?

Tags: r, matrix, graph, network-analysis

I would like to visualize an inter-organizational network based on an individual data frame (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNfUjySsodqxHGyH1bX-ZDvJzd4GBYqQ/view?usp=sharing). A link between firm A and B exists because an individual had a job in firm A before working for firm B (carreer trajectory). Could you help me?

First, I would like to create 3 networks for 3 different time periodes (Subset the dataset for each time period)

```
subdata_period1 <- org[, c("Name", paste0("Carrier.", 1:45), paste0("Year.", 1:45))]

subdata_period2 <- org[, c("Name", paste0("Carrier.", 1:45), paste0("Year.", 1:45))]

subdata_period3 <- org[, c("Name", paste0("Carrier.", 1:45), paste0("Year.", 1:45))]
```

I filter the subdatasets based on the year values

```
subdata_period1 <- subdata_period1[apply(subdata_period1[-(1:45), -(1:45)], 1, function(x) any(x >= 1958 & x <= 1978)), ]

subdata_period2 <- subdata_period2[apply(subdata_period2[-(1:45), -(1:45)], 1, function(x) any(x >= 1979 & x <= 1988)), ]

subdata_period3 <- subdata_period3[apply(subdata_period3[-(1:45), -(1:45)], 1, function(x) any(x >= 1989 & x <= 2010)), ]
```

I use only the first period to show you the problem:

```
names1 <- na.omit(subdata_period1$Name)

carriers1 <- subdata_period1[, grep("^Carrier.", names(subdata_period1))]
```

First, I try to create an empty adjacency matrix

```
adj_matrix1 <- matrix(0, nrow = length(carriers1), ncol = length(carriers1))
```

Second, I iterate through each pair of nodes and check if they share a carrier

```
for (i in 1:(length(carriers1) - 1)) {
  
  for (j in (i + 1):length(carriers1)) {
    
    # Check if the nodes share at least one carrier
    
    if (sum(names1[i] %in% names1[j]) > 0) {
      
      adj_matrix1[i, j] <- 1
      
      adj_matrix1[j, i] <- 1
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Finally, I try to create the graph from the adjacency matrix

```
graph1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(adj_matrix1, mode = "undirected")
```

I try to cluster my network:

```
cluster1 = c("Natixis", "CIC","HSBC France", "BPCE group", "Banque Hervet", "Credit Lyonnais", "BNP Paribas", "Societe General", "Investment banks", "Other banks")

cluster2 = c("Retail", "Media", "Technology", "Heavy industry", "energy sector", "real estate sector", "consulting", "pharmaceutical industry", "other sectors")

V(graph1)$cluster <- ifelse(V(graph1)$carriers1 %in% cluster1, "Banks", ifelse(V(graph1)$carriers1 %in% cluster2, "Private sector", "Public administration"))

colors = c("Banks"= "red", "Private sector" = "blue", "Public administration" = "gold")

V(graph1)$color <- colors[V(graph1)$cluster]
```

Finally, I use ggraph to visualize the first graph:

```
p1 <- ggraph(graph1, layout = "mds") +
  
  geom_node_point(aes(size = size)) +
  
  geom_edge_arc(strength = 0.2, width = 0.5, alpha = 0.15) +
  
  theme_void() +
  
  scale_edge_width(range = c(0.5, 5.5)) +
  
  scale_edge_alpha(range = c(0.2, 5)) +
  
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  
  labs(title = "First period: 1958-1978")

p1

p1 <- ggraph(graph1, layout = "mds") +
  geom_node_point(aes(size = size, label = label) +
                    geom_edge_arc(strength = 0.2, width = 0.5, alpha = 0.15) +
                    theme_void() +
                    scale_edge_width(range = c(0.5, 5.5)) +
                    scale_edge_alpha(range = c(0.2, 5)) +
                    theme(legend.position = "none") +
                    labs(title = "First period: 1958-1978")
```

Many thanks for your help!

I would like to visualize an inter-organizational network based on an individual data frame (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FNfUjySsodqxHGyH1bX-ZDvJzd4GBYqQ/view?usp=sharing). A link between firm A and B exists because an individual had a job in firm A before working for firm B. But that doesn't work.

Comment: Removing blanks and "N/A"s from the the 3rd line of your data gives "ARMAND Loic Marie Retail 1984 Retail 1990 Retail 1993 Retail 1995 Retail 1995 Retail 2000 Retail 2002 Retail 2003"  How should this be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You have not answered my question so I will assume that if the data contains two or more entry with the same name then these entries are to be combined into one.

Algorithm:

```
LOOP over lines in input
    CLEAR career vector
    PARSE line into tokens separated by ","
    LOOP over names in tokens
         APPEND unique names to career vector
    LOOP N1 over names in career vector except last
        LOOP N2 over name in career vector that follow N1
             STORE LINK N1->N2
```

Here is the first few lines of output output

```
ACHARD Pierre Claude Paul
no links

ANSART Bernard Pierre Marie
Cabinets -> Heavy industry
Cabinets -> Retail
Heavy industry -> Retail
Ministry of Economy -> Cabinets
Ministry of Economy -> Heavy industry
Ministry of Economy -> Retail

ARMAND Loic Marie

ARSAC Francois Paul Marie Joseph
 Caisse des d‚p“ts et consignations -> BPCE group
 Caisse des d‚p“ts et consignations -> Cr‚dit Lyonnais
 Caisse des d‚p“ts et consignations -> HSBC France
"the Ministry of Labour, Employment and Population" ->  Caisse des d‚p“ts et consignations
"the Ministry of Labour, Employment and Population" -> BPCE group
"the Ministry of Labour, Employment and Population" -> Cr‚dit Lyonnais
"the Ministry of Labour, Employment and Population" -> HSBC France
BPCE group -> Cr‚dit Lyonnais
HSBC France ->  Caisse des d‚p“ts et consignations
HSBC France -> BPCE group
HSBC France -> Cr‚dit Lyonnais

ASSELINEAU Francois Didier
Natixis -> Ministry of Economy

AUBE-MARTIN Philippe Marc Andr‚
Investment banks -> Real estate sector
Ministry of Economy -> Investment banks
Ministry of Economy -> Real estate sector
```

You can find the complete output at https://github.com/JamesBremner/org-graph/blob/main/bin/links.txt

I do not know R, but it may be helpful to look at the C++ code implementing this:

```
void read(const std::string& fname )
{
    std::ifstream ifs( fname );
    if( ! ifs.is_open() )
        throw std::runtime_error(
            "Cannot open input"        );
    std::string line;
    getline(ifs,line );
    while( getline(ifs,line ))
    {
        auto v = ParseCSV(line);
        std::vector<std::string> career;
        std::cout << v[0] << "\n";
        for( int col = 1; col < v.size(); col+= 2) {
            std::string firm(v[col]);
            if( firm.empty() )
                continue;
            if( firm == "N / A")
                continue;
            career.push_back( firm );
        }
        if( career.size() < 2 ) {
            std::cout << "no links\n\n";
            continue;
        }
        std::set<std::pair<std::string,std::string>> setlink;
        for( int i1 = 0; i1 < career.size()-1; i1++ )
            for( int i2 = i1+1; i2 < career.size(); i2++ )
            {
                if( career[i1] != career[i2])
                    setlink.insert(std::make_pair(career[i1],career[i2]));
            }
        for( auto& l : setlink )
            std::cout << l.first <<" -> "<< l.second << "\n";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

The complete application code can be found at https://github.com/JamesBremner/org-graph